# How to write a string in italics in jinja template

Tags: jinja2

I have string in jinja template. I want to write this in italics.
e.g. - in my template I write `{{ title }}` and my title is "Hello world".
And my desire output is "*Hello* world". How can I do this in jinja template?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

One way is for you to breakdown your content.

```
    // YAML
    title:
      highlighted: "Hello"
      body: " World"

    // JINJA template
    {{ highlighted + body }}
```

Another way is for you to escape html tags buy using filters. You can learn more here: 
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#working-with-manual-escaping

```
    // Yaml file
    title: 
    "Hello World"

    // Jinja template
    {{ title|e }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Italic is not related to jinja2 but to your HTML code.

You can enclose your `{{ title }}` with

```
<i>{{ title }}</i>
```

But even better you should use CSS to format your output.